# Debugging an Outlook 2007 script fired by a rule

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2007

I'm trying to debug an Outlook 2007 VBA script that's fired by a rule. I've set a breakpoint in the script but it doesn't get hit.

The script is actually a `Sub` in the `ThisOutlookSession` object.

When I run the rule on a specified folder nothing seems to happen.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

I've added a `MsgBox "Processing: " & mailItem.Subject` to the script and that pops up just fine when I run the rule. However I can't seem to get the script to stop on breakpoints.

Comment: The MsgBox is a good idea.  I too would like to know how to line-debug scripts run inside a rule.

Comment: I know this question is old, but it's still unanswered. Can you post your code and what conditions would cause it to execute?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you may not be doing anything wrong, because I have experienced exactly the same behaviour.

However, in order to debug your VBA, I suggest that you create a macro (via the Tools|Macro|Macros menu) that calls your script function with a test e-mail item that you create in the macro.

Maybe something like this:

```
Sub TestScript()
    Dim testMail As MailItem
    Set testMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    testMail.Subject = "Test subject"
    testMail.Body = "Test body"
    Project1.ThisOutlookSession.YourScriptForDebugging testMail
End Sub
```

This way you can "Step Into" the macro via that Macro dialog again, and do all the debugging you need. It solved my problem, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nick. I've long since upgraded to Outlook 2010 and the problem seen in 2007 doesn't exist in 2010. I can hit breakpoints as happy as Larry now. Your suggest does work on 2010 as well and I would guess would on 2007 as well if it was still around.

Comment: @Nick I can put breakpoints in the script. But I can't see the values stored in variables and stuff. How do I see that?

Comment: @PrateekNarendra once you have the execution paused at a breakpoint, you can use the "Immediate" window to print the values of any variable or expression.

Comment: @Nick - the best way is to put the variables in the watch window.. I figured it out but thanks for your help

Comment: @PrateekNarendra - You're so right - it's a long time since I was poking around in macro-land and I'd forgotten about that!

Comment: @Nick - I did all this only to realize at the end that macros arent supported in Outlook Mac :P Looks like itll only work in a few laptops in our team :P

Answer (score 0):

Any existing item can be used to test code that requires one.

```
Sub passOpenItem()
    'first open an item
    codeRequiringItemParameter ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
End Sub

Sub passSeletion()
    'first select an item
    codeRequiringItemParameter ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
End Sub

Sub codeRequiringItemParameter(itm As Object)
    Debug.Print "TypeName: " & TypeName(itm)
    Debug.Print "Class...: " & itm.Class
End Sub
```