# Outlook 2013 vba breakpoints not being hit

Tags: vba, outlook

in Outlook 2013 I have created a rule for incoming messages which triggers a vba script.  That script does run (MsgBox works) but in the vba editor no breakpoints are ever hit, nor does the Stop statement break execution.

Does anyone know how to enable vba breakpoints in Outlook 2013?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See if stepping through this is sufficient.

```
Sub TestScript()
    Dim testMail As MailItem
    Set testMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    testMail.Subject = "Test subject"
    testMail.Body = "Test body"
    Project1.ThisOutlookSession.YourScriptForDebugging testMail
End Sub
```

From [Debugging an Outlook 2007 script fired by a rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029141/debugging-an-outlook-2007-script-fired-by-a-rule)