# How to automatically save attachments from Outlook?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to automatically save all attachments from emails with a certain subject line to a folder.  I have tried implementing multiple solutions from other questions on SO and other sources but they don't work.
I'm generally trying to follow the process outlined here: https://windowsreport.com/outlook-rule-download-attachments/

I have the below script in the VBA editor.

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String

sSaveFolder = "H:\temp\_nre_POs\"
For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
Set oAttachment = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

I have also created the rule below to handle to subject line. The rule moving emails to the _Invoices folder has been in place and working fine for months, I just added the 'Run Script' option.  I don't get any errors when running the rule on existing emails in the inbox, but I also don't have any attachments showing up in the destination folder.  Ideally this should run in the background, but I'm open to a more manual process.
[Pic of outlook rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhyHd.png)

EDIT:  I eventually got this to work using the script below.  It may be a bit messy but it works.

```
Public Sub Application_Startup()

Dim MItem As MailItem
Dim oAttachment As Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String
Dim oDefInbox As Folder
Dim targetFolder As Folder
Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
Dim Item As Object

Set oDefInbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set targetFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("_Invoices")

sSaveFolder = "H:\temp\_nre_POs"
For Each MItem In targetFolder.Items
    If MItem.UnRead = True Then
        For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
            oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
            Set oAttachment = Nothing
        Next oAttachment
        MItem.UnRead = False
    End If
Next MItem

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use event Application_NewMail in ThisOutlookSession module, that ["occurs when one or more new email messages are received in the Inbox"](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmail):

```
Private Sub Application_NewMail()
    Set myOlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    Set myNamespace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myItem = myFolder.Items(1)
    SaveAttachmentsToDisk myItem
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, where would I insert the destination folder for attachments to be saved in?

Comment: It is already specified in the SaveAttachmentsToDisk procedure you provided: sSaveFolder = "H: \ temp \ _nre_POs \"

Answer (score 0):

In this situation rules are buggy. Remove the move from the rule. Put the move action in the code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As MailItem)

Dim oAttachment As Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String
Dim oDefInbox As folder
Dim targetFolder As folder

sSaveFolder = "H:\temp\_nre_POs\"
For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
    oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
    Set oAttachment = Nothing
Next

Set oDefInbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

' where the Invoices folder is directly below the Inbox
Set targetFolder = oDefInbox.folders("Invoices")

' If Invoices is nested deeper - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48916736/1571407
'  in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322432/using-visual-basic-to-access-subfolder-in-inbox

MItem.Move targetFolder

End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried to implement this solution but keep running into the same issue.  When I assign just this script to a rule and run it in my inbox (I choose the option to access rules on server rather than client, if that matters), it seems to execute but I don't see any attachments in the destination folder.  I also don't have the option to run the script from the editor.  When I hit the "Run" button it just brings up the box to select macro, and doesn't show SaveAttachmentsToDisk.  Could this be something in my settings?

Comment: @SQLSqirrel `SaveAttachmentsToDisk` cannot run independently. You have to pass `MItem` into the code. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58049467/1571407