# How to auto forward an email from a specific sender and with a specific subject?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to auto forward an email from a specific sender and with a specific subject to a list of new recipients.

When I create a Run a Script Rule, my script is not shown.

1. Add my script via VBA Editor
2. Rules > Manage Rules & Alerts > Run a script
3. Select Run a script action -> Can not Select my script (script not show)

```vb
Option Explicit
 
Public WithEvents objInbox As Outlook.Folder
Public WithEvents objInboxItems As Outlook.Items
 
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objInbox = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set objInboxItems = objInbox.Items
End Sub
 
Private Sub objInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objForward As Outlook.MailItem
 
    Dim xStr1 As String
    Dim xStr2 As String
 
    If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
        Set objMail = Item
 
        If (objMail.SenderEmailAddress = "T@com") And (objMail.Subject = "ZZZZZ") Then
            Set objForward = objMail.Forward
            GoTo commonOutput
        End If
 
    End If
    Exit Sub
 
commonOutput:
    With objForward
        .HTMLBody = xStr1 & xStr2 & Item.HTMLBody
        .Display
    End With
 
Release:
    Set myFwd = Nothing
 
End Sub
```

Comment: `objInboxItems_ItemAdd` should run automatically when an item is added to the inbox. Open an item you think should trigger ItemAdd code to test the logic. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58049467/1571407

Comment: Run a script is usually disabled. You could search for how to reenable but it is not applicable here.

Answer (score 0):

VBA script which can be assigned to a rule should have the following signature:

```
Public Sub Test(item as object)
  ' your code 
End Sub
```

Your existing code does almost the same without rules. It handles the `ItemAdd` event for the `Inbox` folder, so you just need to replace the `Display` method call with `Send`:

```
Private Sub objInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objForward As Outlook.MailItem

    Dim xStr1 As String
    Dim xStr2 As String

    If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
        Set objMail = Item

        If (objMail.SenderEmailAddress = "T@com") And (objMail.Subject = "ZZZZZ") Then
            Set objForward = objMail.Forward
            GoTo commonOutput
        End If

    End If
    Exit Sub

   commonOutput:
    With objForward
        .HTMLBody = xStr1 & xStr2 & Item.HTMLBody
        .Send
    End With

Release:
    Set myFwd = Nothing

End Sub
```