# Script to automatically create Outlook calendar entry upon receiving email with Zoom link

Tags: vba, automation, outlook

I get an email every single week that has the following format:

```
【11/20 Zoom Information】

ID: 123 4567 8901
URL: https://zoom.us/j/12345678901?pwd=XYZ123XYZ123XYZ123XYZ123
Password: 112233
```

The email is not always from the same person but has the following subject line:

> [Company Group Meeting] Zoom ID & Password for November 27th

Basically the subject line would have the same string "`[Company Group Meeting] Zoom ID & Password for`" with only the month and date changing.

I want to create an automation, so whenever I receive the above email, Outlook would automatically create a calendar entry set with the date provided in the email with its year set as the current year at 8-9a.m.

Also I want to set the `Location` as the Zoom link in the email. Thus, I have created the following VBA script:

```vb
Sub CreateCalendarEvent(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim olZoomLink As String
    Dim olSubject As String
    Dim olBody As String
    Dim olStart As Date
    Dim olEnd As Date
    Dim olDate As Date
    Dim olExistingAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    
    'Get the Zoom link from the email body
    olZoomLink = GetZoomLink(Item.Body)
    
    'Get the subject, body from the email
    olSubject = Item.Subject
    olBody = Item.Body
    
    'Get the date from the email body
    olDate = GetDate(Item.Body)
    
    'Set the start and end time to 8-9am JST on the extracted date
    olStart = olDate + TimeValue("08:00:00")
    olEnd = olDate + TimeValue("09:00:00")
    
    'Check for existing appointments with the same subject and start time
    Set olExistingAppt = olFolder.Items.Find("[Subject] = '" & olSubject & "' AND [Start] = '" & olStart & "'")
    
    'If no existing appointment is found, create a new one
    If olExistingAppt Is Nothing Then
        Set olAppt = olFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
        
        'Set the properties of the calendar event
        With olAppt
            .Subject = olSubject
            .Body = olBody
            .Start = olStart
            .End = olEnd
            .Location = olZoomLink
            .ReminderSet = True
            .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15
            .MeetingStatus = olNonMeeting 'Change this to olNonMeeting to avoid sending a meeting request
            .Display
            '.Send 'Comment out this line to avoid sending a meeting request
        End With
    End If
    
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
    Set olFolder = Nothing
    Set olAppt = Nothing
    Set olExistingAppt = Nothing
End Sub

'...existing GetZoomLink and GetDate functions...
```

and then I created a rule that will run the script when a message with a certain string in its subject line arrives. To do this, I did the following:

- Rules > Manage Rules & Alerts
- New Rule > Apply rule on messages I receive
- with specific words in the subject or body
- Clicked on **specific words** and entered "`[Company Group Meeting] Zoom ID & Password for`" > Add > Ok
- Next > run a script
- Clicked on **a script** and selected "Project1.ThisOutlookSession.CreateCalendarEvent"(name of the VBA script I created) > Ok > Next
- Entered name of rule > Checked "Turn on this rule" > Finish > Ok

However, for some reason, even though I'm receiving the weekly email with the above format, the script isn't running to create a new calendar entry. I'd appreciate it if anyone could point out any errors in my code or if I've made any mistake in the procedures I've followed.

Comment: Verify the logic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029141/debugging-an-outlook-2007-script-fired-by-a-rule